# Prevent iOS from killing App after a few minutes

Tags: ios, swift, background, background-task

I'd like to prevent iOS from killing my app after a few minutes.
I've read this thread here on SO: [Prevent iOS from killing my app after 3 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035461/prevent-ios-from-killing-my-app-after-3-minutes) . It says that if I have no backgroundtasks longer than 3 minutes my app wont be killed. Can someone verify that this is true? Because my background-task is not running longer than 3 minutes and even though my app gets killed after this time.
My background-task is a timer that updates a widget. Heres some code:

```
self.backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
        self?.endBackgroundTask()
//endBackGroundTask looks like this
UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
//
    }
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

.

```
// at the beginning of the class
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

.

```
// in viewWillDisappear
self.timer.invalidate()
    if self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        self.endBackgroundTask()

    }
```

Comment: You can't run timers indefinitely in the background; after 3 minutes your app will be terminated for exceeding background time.  There should be no need to update anything continually when your app isn't in the foreground.  This isn't efficient for battery use.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by "background task" since you reference `viewWillDisappear`; If what you really mean is that you have a timer running while your app is active to update your UI periodically, then that is not  a background task and you do not need to use `beginBackgroundTask`; You only need to do use this if you want to perform work when your app would normally be suspended (ie the user presses the home button to move to another app).  If you just want a timer ticking when your app is in the foreground simple delete all of that background task stuff.

Comment: The timer literally counts down the time and updates either the current view or the corresponding widget depending on wether the app state is .active oder .background.

Comment: Right, so the standard approach to that sort of thing is to use a timer when your app is active and then when it moves to the background, you save a timestamp.  When your app returns to the foreground you can calculate the elapsed time and update your UI.  You can even schedule a local notification as the app enters the background to show a notification at the appropriate time.

Comment: But then I wouldn‘t be able to show ticking seconds in my Widget, which is a really useful feature of my app I‘d lile to keep.

Comment: By "widget" do you mean a Today widget?  If so, then that is the job of your today extension and again, that timer should only run when your widget is actually displayed

Comment: I'm corresponding with my widget via userDefaults: `UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "suitname")?.setValue("00:00", forKey: "timeLeft")` . I also throw a notification if the timer finishes while the app is in background.

Comment: Instead of putting the time remaining in user defaults, put the end `Date`, that way you don't need to keep updating it and the widget can calculate the time remaining itself.

Comment: Thats a good idea but it still doesnt get rid of the background task because i still need to throw a notification when the timer finishes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164236/discussion-between-paulw11-and-larsgvb).

Comment: thanks a lot. im currently only on the phone. im joining the chat as soon as Im on my development pc!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to structure your app so that it doesn't require continual execution in the background.  As I understand it, your app shows a count down timer and can show the same count down timer in a Today Widget.  The approach I would use is follows:

- Store the "end date" for the timer in user defaults to share with your widget
- When your app is in the foreground, use a `Timer` to periodically update your UI
- When your Widget is being displayed use a `Timer` in the widget to periodically update its UI
- When your app moves to the background, schedule a local notification for the expiration time
- When your app moves back to the foreground, you can cancel that scheduled notification if it hasn't yet fired.
- Support app restoration for those cases where your app is legitimately terminated (e.g. due to memory pressure or being suspended for a long period)

If you do this then you never need to call `beginBackgroundTask`.  If you do call `beginBackgroundTask` and don't call `endBackgroundTask` within 3 minutes of entering the background, then your app will be terminated, even if you aren't using any CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't run a background task for longer than 3 minutes unless you are a turn-by-turn navigation app or an audio player. Apple doesn't allow it by design.

Comment: I know that, but in the thread I linked in my question it says that if your app doesnt do anything in background (or not longer than 3 mimutes) it doesnt get killed so that there is no need for restoration. I'd like to reproduce that behavior because my app doesn't need background time longer than 3 mins, but it is essential that it is resumed in the same state as it has been left.

Comment: Apps get moved to the background very briefly when the user switches apps. Unless they ask for extra background time (max 3 minutes) they then get switched to the suspended state, where they are still in memory but no longer get background time. Once an app is suspended it can be terminated at any time thereafter without warning, and there is no way to stop it. You might get a resume without being killed, or you might be killed. You have no control of that.

Comment: You are supposed to fully save app state when you find out you are going to be suspended. If you get resumed, great. If you get killed while suspended, you're supposed to restore your saved state.

Comment: I am saving my app state, but every time it is loaded the viewstack is beeing loaded visibly for the user (like he is programmatically navigate to the place where he left of). I dont like this behaviour and I would lile to avoid it as many times as possible, because the use case of my is that it is normal that the users enters something, puts the phone away for a few minutes and then has to enter something again. This currently leads to almost always restoring the app state.

Comment: hi, if I am not submitting my app to Apple App Store, instead, I am submitting to my company app store (AirWatch), will the long running background still work?

Answer (score 2):

Your background task is a timer that is running longer than 3 minutes.  So your app is correctly being killed.  Consider it confirmed as that is Apple's design.

It's not what your timer is executing that is killing the app, it's the timer itself.

You can read up on [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for more information.

> Always try to avoid doing any background work unless doing so improves the overall user experience. An app might move to the background because the user launched a different app or because the user locked the device and is not using it right now. In both situations, the user is signaling that your app does not need to be doing any meaningful work right now. Continuing to run in such conditions will only drain the device’s battery and might lead the user to force quit your app altogether. So be mindful about the work you do in the background and avoid it when you can.

Comment: So even if I invalidate the timer the measured background time runs on and therefore reaches the 3min-limit?

Comment: @LarsGvB It's looking like you're on a good path with Paulw11.  I've agreed with everything he has said on the public chat.  I'm positive the private chat was beneficial.  In the meantime, don't forget to mark an answer for this question to close it out.  Cheers.

Comment: I couldn‘t test the things yet. As soon as I got time to that and if they solve the problem I‘ll do that.

Comment: @RBradshaw FYI, chats opened from comments aren't "private"; You can click the link and read what was said, or even join in, if you have sufficient reputation.